# Custom Rounding numbers using nearby 0.05

Tags: javascript

I want to round the numbers like below , I have asked the question in stack overflow before 6 months and I got solution and it was working fine

```
12.910 - 12.90
12.920 - 12.90
12.930 - 12.90
12.940 - 12.90
12.941 - 12.95
12.950 - 12.95

12.960 - 12.95
12.970 - 12.95
12.980 - 12.95
12.990 - 12.95
12.991 - 13.00 
13.000 - 13.00
```

But its not working for following numbers

```
Input 32.34 - expected 32.30 - but got 32.35
Input 33.09 - expected 33.05 - but got 33.10
```

Whereas other numbers like `33.34 , 23.34` gives correct output `33.30 and 23.30`

Here is the function

```
function customRound(num) {
     intermediateResult = Math.ceil(num*100)/100;
     return Math.floor(intermediateResult*20)/20;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to round to the nearest integer after doing `num * 100`. Right now you are going rounding up to the next integer by using `Math.ceil.`

Try using [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round#Decimal_rounding). I hope it helps:

**Update:** You will also have to use `toFixed` together with `parseFloat` to solve precision errors in the multiplication.

```js
function customRound(num) {
  intermediateResult = Math.round(parseFloat((num * 100).toFixed(2))) / 100;
  return Math.floor(intermediateResult * 20) / 20;
}

console.log(customRound(32.34));
console.log(customRound(33.09));
console.log(customRound(67.445));
console.log(customRound(69.195));
```

If you want to show 2 decimal places, use [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) together with [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) like so: `parseFloat(Math.round(res * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)`:

```js
function customRound(num) {
  intermediateResult = Math.round(parseFloat((num * 100).toFixed(2))) / 100;
  const res = Math.floor(intermediateResult * 20) / 20;
  return parseFloat(Math.round(res * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)
}

console.log(customRound(32.34));
console.log(customRound(33.09));
console.log(customRound(67.445));
console.log(customRound(57.244));
```

---

**2nd Update:**

```js
function getIntString(num, factor = 1) {
  return (num * factor + "").split('.')[0];
}

function customRound(num) {
  const int = getIntString(num);
  const decimal = (num + "").split('.')[1];
  let precision;
  if (decimal) {
    if (decimal.length === 2) {
      precision = decimal + 0;
    } else {
      precision = decimal.slice(0, 3);
    }
  } else {
    return num;
  }
  const specificPrecision = precision.slice(1);
  if (specificPrecision > 40 && specificPrecision < 91) {
    precision = precision.slice(0, 1) + 50;
    return parseFloat(`${int}.${precision}`);
  } else if (specificPrecision >= 91) {
    if (parseInt(precision.slice(0, 1)) === 9) {
      return Math.ceil(num);
    } else {
      return (Math.floor(num * 10 + 1))/10;
    }
  } else {
    return parseInt(getIntString(num, 10)) / 10;
  }
}


const logResult = (inp) => `Input: ${inp}, Result: ${customRound(inp)}`;


console.log(logResult(18.095));
console.log(logResult(12.991));
console.log(logResult(12.191));
console.log(logResult(12.990));
console.log(logResult(12.910));
console.log(logResult(12.440));
console.log(logResult(12.441));
console.log(logResult(12.921));
console.log(logResult(67.445));
console.log(logResult(57.244));
console.log(logResult(58.344));
console.log(logResult(69.195));
```

Comment: 67.445 should be 67.45 , but got 67.40 ... and 69.195 should be 69.20 but got 69.15

Comment: @Graciewilliams sorry this is because of a precision error with multiplication. I updated my answer.

Comment: 57.244 should be 57.25 ... but its 57.20  and 58.344 should be  58.35 , but its 58.30

Comment: anything above 0.x40

Comment: Try my second update, or [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dankreiger/eqjv29b4/13/)

Comment: 18.095 should be 18.10 , but its 18.11 or 18.09 sometimes

Comment: @Graciewilliams I hope it works this time - I updated it again for that test case - if not I will try to find the time to write this out in a mocha or jest test

Comment: I was already testing in nodejs , it was working fine like butter now , thank you

Comment: No problem. I'm glad it helped :)